# dplyr pipe operator with save()

Tags: r, dplyr

The dplyr pipe `%>%` syntax does not seem to work with the `save()` function.  When I run this code below, only `x`, and not `y`, is restored as a variable in the workspace.  Why?  Is this a bug or do I not understand the pipe functionality sufficiently?

```
require(dplyr)

x <- 2
save(x, file = 'x.rdat')

y <- 3
y %>% save(file = 'y.rdat')

rm(x)
rm(y)

load('x.rdat')
load('y.rdat')

ls()
```

Answer (score 6):

`save()` takes the *name* of an object (or objects), or a symbol, not the object itself (and the resulting file can store multiple objects).  The symbol interpretation most likely gets messed up in the `dplyr` pipeline. Maybe `saveRDS()`/`readRDS()` will do what you want ... ?

```
require(dplyr)
y <- 3
y %>% saveRDS(file = 'y.rds')
rm(y) 
readRDS('y.rds') -> y
ls()
```

(If I try to `deparse(substitute(x))` on a function that's called from a pipe, the variable that's passed is called `"."` - that won't work very well ...)